# Using Nlog to write custom object to an sql server database table

Tags: c#, wcf, nlog

I'm using nlog to record to an sql database via aWCP service application using C#.NET 4.0, and this works ok:

NLOG Config

```
<target name="database" xsi:type="Database">
  <connectionString>
    CONNECTION DETAILS REMOVED
  </connectionString>
  <commandText>
    insert into tablex (
    Application, Logged, Level, Message,
    ServerName, Port, Url, Https,
    ServerAddress, RemoteAddress,
    Logger, Callsite, Exception
    ) values (
    @Application, @Logged, @Level, @Message,
    @ServerName, @Port, @Url, @Https,
    @ServerAddress, @RemoteAddress,
    @Logger,@CallSite, @Exception
    );
  </commandText>
  <parameter name="@application" layout="" />
  <parameter name="@logged" layout="${date:format=yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fff" />
  <parameter name="@level" layout="${level}" />
  <parameter name="@message" layout="${message}" />


  <parameter name="@serverName" layout="" />
  <parameter name="@port" layout="" />
  <parameter name="@url" layout="" />
  <parameter name="@https" layout="" />

  <parameter name="@serverAddress" layout="" />
  <parameter name="@remoteAddress" layout="" />

  <parameter name="@logger" layout="${logger}" />
  <parameter name="@callsite" layout="" />
  <parameter name="@exception" layout="${exception:tostring}" />
</target>
```

I'm trying to record a custom object that is returned by a web service, and wondering if this can be easily stored?

I was trying something along the lines of:

```
CustomType returnPayload = controller.TransferPatient(request)
logger.Debug<CustomType>("Return Payload",returnPayload);
```

But not sure how to write it back to the @CallSite parameter that is a nvarchar(MAX) type in sql server.

Comment: Can you convert the object to JSON and store the string in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Found this:

```
logger.Debug("Return Payload {@value1}", new { requestInfo = request, Return = returnPayload});
```

This writes the value using:

```
<parameter name="@message" layout="${message}" />
```

Comment: Although this solution works, it doesn't follow the spirit of using the TState property.